# How to properly return value from a recursive call in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, lisp

My goal is to provide a list to a `plus-minus` method so that it may traverse through every possible circumstance in which if any given number of elements are made negative and then subtracted from the sum of the remaining positive numbers there is a chance that that number may be either found or not found within the original list.

For example: if we feed `plus-minus` a list of (3 1 2), then `plus-minus` should return `#t` once it reaches (3 1 -2), since 4 - 2 = 2 and 2 is within the original list of (3 1 2).

I have a separate method from `plus-minus`, `ref-check`, which is used to determine whether or not the target number is within the list. So, in the example provided, its job would be to determine whether or not 2 exists within the original list of (3 1 2). Since it does exist within the original list, `ref-check` is to return `1` for `#t`.

My issue currently is that `ref-check` does return #t back to `plus-minus`, but the method seems to continue regardless.

I feel as though there is a simple solution to this problem.

Working code:

```
;returns true if the element is in the list otherwise false
(define ref-check(lambda (list element)
            (cond
             ((null? list) 0)
             ((= element (car list)) 1)
             (else (ref-check (cdr list) element)))))


;main calculation
(define plus-minus(lambda (L sum1 sum2)
                    (cond
                      ((null? L) #f)
                      ((= (ref-check L (- sum1 sum2)) 1) #t)
                      (else (plus-minus (cdr L) (+ sum1 (car L)) sum2)
                            (plus-minus (cdr L) sum1 (+ sum2 (car L)))))))
```

Example input: `(plus-minus '(7 5 1 2) 0 0)`
Example result: `#t`

Edits: Correctness and clarity

Comment: You probably want `(else (or (plus-minus ...) (plus-minus ...)))`. As it is now, the return value from the first `plus-minus` is completely ignored.

Comment: Should `(3 1 2 400)`  return true or false?

Comment: jkiiski - you are correct as it does achieve what I wanted out of that line. Daniel - `(3 1 2 400)` should always return `#f`. Now comes to the question as to how I ensure `ref-check` always receives the original list, and not one that had been eaten at via `cdr`. Currently `(7 5 1 2)` returns `#t`, but `(7 1 5 2)` does not due to this occurring. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start answering the questions:

> My issue currently is that `ref-check` does return <s>`#t`</s>[`1`] back to `plus-minus`, but the method seems to continue regardless.

In the case that `ref-check` returns `1` to your calling function, further recursive calls **aren't** made *further down from the current call stack*. So, after `ref-check` returned, the calling `plus-minus` *also* returns.

**But** it returns to the function which called it, which *may* be "you" (i.e. the toplevel) but *more likely* will be "itself". An example might illustrate that better:

Let's call `(plus-minus '(3 1 2) 0 0)`: This will land in the `else` branch of the `cond`, calling first `(plus-minus '(1 2) 3 0)`. That will land in the `else` branch, too, and thus first call `(plus-minus '(2) 5 0)` (which will ultimately return `#f`, thus we ignore it) and then `(plus-minus '(2) 3 1)`. In **that** invocation of `plus-minus`, it'll hit the branch of the `cond` that returns `#t` due to `ref-check` (`3-1 == 2` being part of `(1 2)`). The function returns to its caller, which is actually "in the `else` branch" of the first invocation of `plus-minus`. There, you discard the returned value, and unconditionally call `(plus-minus '(1 2) 0 3)`, which will in turn make further calls to both `ref-check` and `plus-minus`.

Visually, showing part of the call-stack:

```
(plus-minus '(3 1 2) 0 0)
  ;; In else
  (plus-minus '(1 2) 3 0)
     ;; In else
     (plus-minus '(2) 5 0)
        ;; Details discarded, returns #f
        ;; <== #f
     ;; Discard #f from above, and call
     (plus-minus '(2) 3 1)
       ;; ref-check returned 1, so return #t
       ;; <== #t
     ;; <== #t
  ;; Still in the else, got #t, discard, then
  (plus-minus '(1 2) 0 3)
     ;; ...
```

To get rid of this you need to make the second recursive call **only** if the first doesn't already return `#t`. This can be easily achieved by wrapping both calls in an `(or ...)`.

> [..] how I ensure ref-check always receives the original list,

Pass the original list as an additional parameter down every call of `plus-minus`.

> `(3 1 2 400)` should always return `#f`

With your current logic, that won't happen. Since you call `ref-check` also with partially computed `sum1` and `sum2` (i.e. not all elements of your list "decided" yet whether they're negative or not) the above will yield `#t`.

To get your desired behavior, you need to call `ref-check` *only* when all elements of the list are either added to `sum1` or `sum2`, thus when there are no more elements to process, i.e. when the list is empty.

Now, some remarks:

- Don't use `0` and `1` to represent truthiness, in Scheme you should use `#f` to represent `false` and anything else (`#t` if you cannot meaningfully return anything) for `true`.
- Indentation and spacing: You should really keep to the established standards here. Normally, your editor should take care of that.
- Don't speak of "methods". It's called *functions*.

I'm not providing "final working" code to allow you to implement the above mentioned fixes yourself.